# How does PancakeSwap Lotery work? What is the Contract flow..?

Tags: contract-development, bsc, pancakeswap, binance

I'm trying to figure out how the Lottery works... What is the flow..? How are Contracts connected?

If I look at the Contract they listed ob BscScan (0x3C3f2049cc17C136a604bE23cF7E42745edf3b91) and check transaction history back to about the end of april and before that, transactions kinda make sense to me. You would send cake to the contract and recive tickets (I'm not sure on how exactly...). Example: https://bscscan.com/tx/0xea770f1f15855ac45dde2b06471f3ee3c2ebc585aea0d332fab994098fe0d0c7. At list that's how I think it worked. But than something changed...

My end goal was to see if there is a way to see who the winners were and how the Cake was distributed...

I'm a noob in this space, so any help would be much appreciated, ty :)